# Ошибка в файле jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Tags: jquery, консоль, type-error

При работе в любом html-документе в консоли всегда высвечивается ошибка, при том что я не использую jquery ни в одной работе. Сам файл jquery находится здесь -C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mnlohknjofogcljbcknkakphddjpijak\1.4.4_0\js\lib
При удалении этого файла из папки ошибка не исчезает, а файл, через некоторое время снова в ней появляется
[image: скрин ошибки]

Подскажите в чем тут проблема и как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: У вас в браузере расширение, удалите его и ошибка перестанет быть

Comment: Arcadiy, спасибо большое. Отключил расширение Переводчик uLanguage и ошибка исчезла

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста